Angular Karma ChromeHeadless opens blank page
I recently updated Angular (and Karma) to their latest versions, and now I get a weird blank page that shows up. For some reason, even though the blank page is there, when I click on it (or right click) it acts like it is not even there. Meaning if the blank page is in front op my IDE, I can click on it the blank page, and it acts like I am click on the IDE instead, almost as if it isn't even there. I do have the browser set to ChromeHeadless, and it used to not open up a weird blank page.
I just don't want anything to open up when running tests. I can just browse to the url to view karma when I need to.

All of my unit tests (528 of them) are successful.
I did just notice this, I also just updated Angular material v14 to v18 as well. Seems to be about all unit tests since the updates.
ERROR: 'NG0304: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element (used in the 'SiteNewsDialogEditComponent' component template):
1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
ERROR: 'NG0304: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element (used in the 'SiteNewsDialogEditComponent' component template):
1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
ERROR: 'NG0304: 'mat-label' is not a known element (used in the 'SiteNewsDialogEditComponent' component template):
1. If 'mat-label' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
2. If 'mat-label' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
ERROR: 'NG0304: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element (used in the 'SiteNewsDialogEditComponent' component template):
1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
ERROR: 'NG0304: 'mat-label' is not a known element (used in the 'SiteNewsDialogEditComponent' component template):                                                                                                  
1. If 'mat-label' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
2. If 'mat-label' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
ERROR: 'NG0304: 'mat-datepicker-toggle' is not a known element (used in the 'SiteNewsDialogEditComponent' component template):                                                                                      
1. If 'mat-datepicker-toggle' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
2. If 'mat-datepicker-toggle' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
ERROR: 'NG0304: 'mat-datepicker' is not a known element (used in the 'SiteNewsDialogEditComponent' component template):                                                                                             
1. If 'mat-datepicker' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
2. If 'mat-datepicker' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
ERROR: 'NG0304: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element (used in the 'SiteNewsDialogEditComponent' component template):                                                                                             
1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
ERROR: 'NG0304: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element (used in the 'SiteNewsDialogEditComponent' component template):                                                                                             
1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
ERROR: 'NG0304: 'mat-label' is not a known element (used in the 'SiteNewsDialogEditComponent' component template):                                                                                                  
1. If 'mat-label' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
2. If 'mat-label' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'


Here is my package.json:
{
  "name": "pivotal",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "20.18.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm run config -- --environment=dev && ng serve",
    "start spanish": "npm run config -- --environment=dev && ng serve --configuration=es",
    "build": "npm run config -- --environment=prod && ng build --configuration production --build-optimizer --localize",
    "install-puppeteer": "cd node_modules/puppeteer && npm run install",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "config": "ts-node ./scripts/setenv.ts",
    "postinstall": "check-node-version --package"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/material": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "^18.2.7",
    "@azure/core-http": "^3.0.4",
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.25.0",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^8.0.0",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/quill": "^2.0.14",
    "ajv": "^8.8.2",
    "angular-auth-oidc-client": "^14.1.5",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.30.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "date-fns-tz": "^1.3.7",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-quill": "^26.0.8",
    "parchment": "^3.0.0",
    "quill": "^2.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.7",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/localize": "^18.2.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^22.7.4",
    "check-node-version": "^4.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "jasmine-auto-spies": "^6.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^2.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "ng-bullet": "^1.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "^23.5.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.4",
    "yargs": "^16.1.0"
  }
}

and my karma.conf.js:
module.exports = function (config) {
  const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
  process.env.CHROME_BIN = puppeteer.executablePath();

  config.set({
    basePath: "",
    frameworks: ["jasmine", "@angular-devkit/build-angular"],
    plugins: [
      require("karma-jasmine"),
      require("karma-chrome-launcher"),
      require("karma-jasmine-html-reporter"),
      require("karma-coverage"),
      require("@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma"),
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: true,
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require("path").join(__dirname, "../coverage"),
      subdir: ".",
      reporters: [
        { type: "html" },
        { type: "text-summary" },
        { type: "lcovonly" },
        { type: "cobertura" },
      ],
    },
    reporters: ["progress"],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ["ChromeHeadless"],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: "ChromeHeadless",
        flags: [
          "--no-sandbox",
          "--disable-gpu",
          "--headless",
          "--disable-translate",
          "--disable-extensions",
          "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
        ],
      },
    },
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: false,
  });
};

Through research and trying to fix this with ChatGPT I changed some settings in karma.conf:
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: "ChromeHeadless",
        flags: [
          "--no-sandbox",
          "--disable-gpu",
          "--headless",
          "--disable-translate",
          "--disable-extensions",
          "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
        ],
      },
    },


Are there any errors or warning in the console before the test execution starts?


pivotal@0.0.0 test
ng test

√ Browser application bundle generation complete.
16 10 2024 08:34:25.993:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
16 10 2024 08:34:26.004:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.4.4 server started at http://localhost:9876/
16 10 2024 08:34:26.005:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadless with concurrency unlimited
16 10 2024 08:34:26.020:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
16 10 2024 08:34:26.984:INFO [Chrome Headless 129.0.0.0 (Windows 10)]: Connected on socket Xv6dG9Njho3Pbn7oAAAB with id 12774242
